# Unzip when file conatins UTF-8 characters in R

Tags: r, file, zip, unzip

I want to unzip folder and rename files from rhat folder in R.

My try with zip package:

```
zip::unzip("my.path", exdir = "mydocument")
unzip_files <- list.files("mydocument", full.names = TRUE)
for (j in seq_along(unzip_files)) {
  file.rename(unzip_files[j], "somefilename")
}
```

The problem is that files in zip document contains UTF-8 characters:

```
16900-19 odb. parcelacija katastar - službeno  više uložaka, čl. 145.doc
```

but when unzipped the files looks like this:

```
16900-19 odb. parcelacija katastar - sluÅ¾beno  viÅ¡e uloÅ¾aka, Äl. 145
```

and I can't rename it beacuse it has this strange characters.

So I need to unzip folder but keep UTF-8 characters or somehow rename file with this strange chracters.

Comment: If the strange character result is `unzip_files`, you can do `Encoding(unzip_files) <- "UTF-8"` and they will be corrected.

Comment: I tried your code on a dummy Word file I created with the same filename as you have, and I get a weird name in File Explorer after unzipping, just like you. But this might be an issue with Windows that the UTF-8 characters are displayed garbled. Have you checked your Windows locale? Perhaps you need to change it to Croatian? (Btw, the renaming part of your code worked for me, so it suggests it's a display issue.)

Comment: @caldwellst, I can change it in R object, but it will stay the same in unzip folder, so that want help.

Comment: It shows utf-8 characters inside folder, so I don't think it is due to windows settings